# an unknown error while using FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Getting a weird error while using signInWithCredential(), but I am able to sign in by signInAnonymously()

Have tried searching and remaking app in facebookDeveloper account.

My Function:

```
Future<UserCredential> _signInWithFacebook() async {
    final loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions: [
      'email',
      'public_profile',
    ]);

    if (loginResult.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      final accessToken = loginResult.accessToken!.token;
      final OAuthCredential credential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken);
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then((value) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
        return value;
      });
    } else {
      return FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
FLTFirebaseAuth: An error occurred while calling method Auth#signInWithCredential, errorOrNil => (null)
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:607
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:167
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:367
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential
package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:433
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential
package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:497
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Did you check your SHA? You also need to add your app to facebook developer account, did you complete this?

Comment: Yes, it has been setup correctly, I am getting profile response from FacebookAuth.instance.login()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps can be helpful if you haven't tried it yet -

1. Check if the firebase app is instantiated at the beginning -> .initializeApp()
2. Firebase Auth doesn't work without initialization
3. If the above two doesn't work, replace google-services.json with a new one. Do a clean build

Comment: Apparently replacing googleServices-info.plist worked, thanks a lot.